# Neo4j.rb ignores id property returning neoId instead

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j

I am trying to add `id` property to my node. Its value is properly saved to neo4j database, which i can confirm with webadmin app. But if I later try to access it or serialize to json this property is set with the value of `neoId`.

I would really need this property and I've read before that I shouldn't use `neoId` as a way to identify objects.

Do you have any idea how to get desired effect?

I should have mentioned that I am using Neo4j.rb with Rails.

Comment: How are you trying to access it? Can you provide the cypher construct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't set the id as a new property. Nodes and relationships always have an identifier property by design. Its value is automatically generated by Neo4j. If you want your own kind of identifier, you can't name it "id".

Comment: But, is it true that I shouldn't use this neo4j's identifier property? I have read that this is an implementation detail, like rowid in relational databases. There is no guarantee that it will be unique for a single instance.

Comment: AFAIK identifiers can be reused which makes them potentionally dangerous to use. If you want a true unique identifier, you'll have to provide one of your own as described in my answer.

Comment: Is there any convention in neo4j for identifiers? I mean naming and how to generate them? I was thinking about using uuid, but this one is a bit long.

Comment: Maybe [RandomStringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html) is an option for you?